# How do I create a pop up modal on successful form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, form-submit

I have an HTML form connected to [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/) form endpoint.

```
 <form action="https://formsubmit.co/my@email.com" method="POST" class="form">
     <input type="text" name="name" required>
     <input type="email" name="email" required>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've added `<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://mydomain.co/thanks.html">` to redirect back to the original page after submission is required.
I've also disabled the reCAPTCHA using `<input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">`, so when the form is submitted, the page just reloads.

The problem is the user doesn't know anything has happened after form submission, the page just loads for some time and then reloads.
I don't want to create another page for this, I actually want to use a modal for it.

I tried adding a `submit` event listener, and when that event is triggered, an `alert` is shown; but the alert shows even before the form submission process begins.

```
function alertSubmit() {
  alert('Your details were successfully received.');
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', alertSubmit);
```

How can I display an `alert` immediately after the form is successfully submitted and not when the `submit` button is clicked?

Comment: Why are you not using the `_next` option to simply specify a "thank you" page the user should be redirected to afterwards? https://formsubmit.co/documentation

Comment: I just edited my post to include that I've used the `_next` option.

@CBroe I don't want to create another page, I actually want to use a modal for it, so I thought if someone could provide an answer to how to use alert, I would be able to try using a modal using the logic.

Comment: Add a query string parameter to your next URL then, and check for that when the page loads.

Comment: @CBroe Can you please post an answer on how to go about that? I don't know how.

Comment: `.../thanks.html?formWasSubmitted`, `if(location.search=='?formWasSubmitted') { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST" class="form">
     <input type="text" name="name" required>
     <input type="email" name="email" required>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.form').on('submit', function(){
            swal("Title", "Message Content", "success", {
  button: "Ok",
});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm content with this.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do following changes:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.form').on('submit', function(){
            alert('Your details were successfully received.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The alert still shows before the form submission process is carried out. It's the same result as using the `submit` event listener in JavaScript.